# No Provisioning Profile was found for your project's Bundle Identifier or your device (after app transfer)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, flutter, app-store-connect

I have transferred my app from one account to another and after that transfer, when I try to run my app code on the Simulator, it's fine, but on iPhone, it gives the this error:

```
No Provisioning Profile was found for your project's Bundle Identifier or your 
device. You can create a new Provisioning Profile for your project in Xcode for 
your team by:
  1- Open the Flutter project's Xcode target with
       open ios/Runner.xcworkspace
  2- Select the 'Runner' project in the navigator then the 'Runner' target
     in the project settings
  3- Make sure a 'Development Team' is selected. 
     - For Xcode 10, look under General > Signing > Team.
     - For Xcode 11 and newer, look under Signing & Capabilities > Team.
     You may need to:
         - Log in with your Apple ID in Xcode first
         - Ensure you have a valid unique Bundle ID
         - Register your device with your Apple Developer Account
         - Let Xcode automatically provision a profile for your app
  4- Build or run your project again

It's also possible that a previously installed app with the same Bundle 
Identifier was signed with a different certificate.

For more information, please visit:
  https://flutter.dev/setup/#deploy-to-ios-devices

Or run on an iOS simulator without code signing
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
2021-06-16 19:24:22.953 ios-deploy[32614:4058557] [ !! ] Error 0xe8008015: A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found. AMDeviceSecureInstallApplication(0, device, url, options, install_callback, 0)
Could not run build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app on 00008020-000504561EE1002E.
Try launching Xcode and selecting "Product > Run" to fix the problem:   
  open ios/Runner.xcworkspace
```

I have changed my Signing Team after the app transfer, maybe that is the problem. I am using Xcode 12.3.

Extra Question:
Also, when I tried yesterday to update my app by sending a new binary to App Store Connect, I got this warning in Gmail:

```
ITMS-90076: Potential Loss of Keychain Access - The previous version of software has an application-identifier value of ['87D7N6U493.com.companyname.app'] and the new version of software being submitted has an application-identifier of ['99ZU5RS2PA.com.companyname.app']. This will result in a loss of keychain access.
```

I think these problems are correlated and if anyone knows how I can fix this, I would be very grateful.

Thank You in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the solution given in error?